# SharePoint exact search not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I am using SharePoint 2010 in one of my environment and am facing the below issue in my search configurations.

while searching with the keyword "l’emploi" under exact search it is returning all the documents which contain either l’ or emploi,

**i.e** it is working as ANY(l’emploi) whereas I want it to search for the exact keyword l’emploi as whole.

can anyone tell me where I am missing a point?

I am generating the URL with custom code.

for exact keyword search, it is like `" *?k=(l’emploi)`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That´s because sharepoint handles special characters in the search query differently. In most cases (as I would expect in yours) they are simply ignored and replaced by a space.

So in fact sharepoint searches for 'l emploi' without any quotation makes sharepoint "tokenizing" your inpot into 2 words and  that the terms "l" and "employ" has to be found in an item (which exactly your results proof). The only thing you could do is to change the search query to "l emploi" (in double quotation) for searching for this phrase (so "l" and "emploi" has to come one after another and not anywhere without relation)

Comment: still its not getting me the result as expected. 

the symbol/character ( ’ ) is a part of the keyword then how does it gets ignored ??

when i search for l’emploi without any quotation mark it gives me the expected document but it also search for l’ OR emploi. which it shouldn't.

anyway to stop it ?

Comment: Can you tell me if i can find an exact reference for the same thing you mentioned in you answer. Any authenticated forum, Like msdn ~@leopold Lerch

Comment: sry, but there is no doku i can tell you. I found it by myself also the hard way. In fact, the special characters are removed already in the indexing process. sharepoint searches for words and phrases (which are words "bounded" between double quotes) and builds it index out of these. and words in literally do not have special characters (or numbers) in it. 
Believe me or not

Comment: but there also another problem if i bound the keyword in double quotes it doesn't search some document in which it has the keyword. whereas as soon as i remove the quotes from the url and hit it again, it gets me the document but with the issues mentioned in the question remaining.